# Improving a Stackoverflow "inspired" badge system to display badges in author page

Tags: plugins, php, author, stackoverflow

I've been modifying a long abandoned plugin project that provides a Stackoverflow inspired badge system for Wordpress. I have upgraded some of its code so it functions with the new Wordpress version.

Please view the plugin code here: http://pastebin.com/kCWWLPL2

The problem is that the original code did not provide a way to echo the badges the user have been awarded. Currently, there is a way of displaying the badges: `<?php rhb_list_badges() ?>` this function will list every single badge in the system.

I want to modify the code so that by adding a function to the author.php page of Wordpress, **it will list the user's awarded badges**. However, my knowledge of PHP is very limited and I have hit a wall.

I was told that this might work:

```
<?php
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
if ($user_id != 0) {
  rhb_list_badges(array('user_ID' => $user_id));
}
?>
```

But all it did was to list the all the badges and not *just* the awarded ones for the user. Maybe something is missing in the above code? I am certain that there must be a way to accomplish this. Do you know how?

**Update:** If we look in the original code, we can see that there is a filter already in place:

```
function rhb_get_badges( $filter = '' ) {

        global $wpdb;

        if ( empty($filter ) ) { $filter = array(); }

        // Select all rows by default
        $sql = 'SELECT badge_id, name, description, type FROM ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'rh_badges b WHERE 1=1 ';

        // If a user ID was entered.
        if ( array_key_exists('user_ID', $filter) ) {

                $user_ID = $filter['user_ID'];

                // Join the rh_user_badges table.
                $sql = 'SELECT b.badge_id, b.name, b.description, b.type
                                FROM ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'rh_badges b,
                                        ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'rh_user_badges ub
                                WHERE b.badge_id = ub.badge_id
                                AND ub.user_id = ' . $user_ID;

        }

        // If a badge ID was entered.
        if ( array_key_exists('badge_ID', $filter) ) {

                $badge_ID = $filter['badge_ID'];

                // Append a WHERE clause to the SQL.
                $sql .= " AND b.badge_id = $badge_ID";
        }

        $badges = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );

        return $badges;
}

function rhb_list_badges( $filter = '' ) {


        if ( empty($filter ) ) { $filter = array(); }

        print '';

                        foreach (rhb_get_badges( $filter ) as $badge) {

                        print '<div class="biobadge"><div class="';

                                        if ( 'gold' == $badge->type )
                                                echo 'bgold';
                                        elseif ( 'silver' == $badge->type )
                                                echo 'bsilver';
                                        elseif ( 'bronze' == $badge->type )
                                                echo 'bbronze';

                                        print '"></div>
                                                ' . $badge->name . '
                                                </div>';
                        }
                        ;
}
```

How would I go about to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get_current_user_id(); gets the current logged in user id and you need the user whos profileUrl is views so try this insted to get the right id:

```
$author = get_user_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'author_name' ) ); 
echo $author->ID;'
```

yep, so instead of your code try this:

```
$author = get_user_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'author_name' ) ); 
if ($author->ID > 0) {
  rhb_list_badges(array('user_ID' => $author->ID));
}
```

Comment: Can you please incorporate your code example with mine and I can run it to see if it works?

Comment: Further guidance and a code example to run would be ideal, cheers for responding.

Comment: i updated my answer

Comment: I tried it but it did not return anything I am afraid. However, I have updated my question if you could please look. The original code already had a filter system in place, if you could kindly look through that update and see if you know how I could use it?

Comment: Forget that. I just made further testings and you were correct, the original code returned the user that is online's badges. How can I change it so that it displays the author's? Maybe there is a typo in your code?

Comment: Good news, I managed to make it work with the following code, this works both inside and outside the loop, although I cannot tell if it is best practice for what I am trying to achieve: <?php
$curauth = (isset($_GET['author_name'])) ? get_user_by('slug', $author_name) : get_userdata(intval($author));
rhb_list_badges(array('user_ID'=>$curauth->ID));
?>

Comment: Although this didnt work, I will accept it as correct for the effort.